# REGEX: IF NAME is in "sentence" THEN MATCH that "sentence"

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas data frame of people and a report of the running race on each row. Each sentence is reporting to a name. eg. "Philip Jeffery started brilliantly. Bob More tripped at the start.". The names can be up to 5 words in length. Therefore I want to be able to match their report to each person. So Philip is on one row of the dataframe and on the Incident report it should say "Philip Jeffery started brilliantly." So I thought REGEX would be perfect, but cannot find anything online about this problem and I am quite new to the engine. This is what I have so far for if the name is one word in length.

```
if len(NameTokens)==1:
    REGEX=r"(^\\s+{}(?:[A-Za-z,;'\"\\s]+[.?!]$))".format(NameTokens[0])
    #print(REGEX)
    RunnerReport=df_merge['Incident Report'].str.extract(REGEX, expand=True)
    print(RunnerReport)
```

NameTokens is the name tokenised into a list, such as ['Philip', 'Jeffery'].

The variable REGEX needs working REGEX because at the moment my REGEX is not returning any results, just NAN values. Again I am new to REGEX.

Thanks!

*UPDATE*. My input is on the GRNZ Incident reports on the GRNZ website, here is one example: https://www.grnz.co.nz/catch-the-action/13000/stewards-report.aspx . I am trying to parse the tables and match each runners name to their report.

e.g. MISS BUCKET (1) - tightened making contact after the start losing ground. Contacted the running rail first turn losing ground. Veterinary examination revealed no abnormality. SPARK 'EM UP (2) - contact several strides after the start. Collided first turn. JETSUN BEAR (3) - bumped after the start then shifted out making contact for a distance back straight. C'EST L'AMOUR (4) - collided first turn. BIGTIME SASSY (5) - shifted in off heels first turn. BRIGHT CONCEPT (6) - bumped entering the final straight and again concluding stages. JINJA LAD (7) - slow away. Inconvenienced back straight making contact for a distance shifting in across heels becoming unbalanced losing ground. Checked rounding the bend shifting out off heels. CRAMPTON (8) - bumped entering the final straight and again concluding stages.

Comment: hey buddy, welcome to SO. thanks for showing your sample code, are you able to show us your sample input and expected output so we can reproduce this? about 5 rows will do.

Comment: I am having difficulty following your description and correlating it to your code. That said, you should not be doubling up on the back slashes ('\') if you are using a raw string as you are doing.

Comment: what would be your expected result from the sample you supplied. are these upper-cased names you want to parse: `MISS BUCKET`,  `SPARK 'EM UP`, `JETSUN BEAR` ... `CRAMPTON` ?

Comment: So each row in the dataframe would be the Runners name, such as MISS BUCKET, JETSUN BEAR.

Comment: So for MISS BUCKET I want to extract for that row “MISS BUCKET (1) - tightened making contact after the start losing ground. Contacted the running rail first turn losing ground. Veterinary examination revealed no abnormality.”

Comment: So if the sentence contains MISS BUCKET I want to capture that sentence, if there are no names then I want to capture that sentence to the previous name captured

Comment: I am now using NLTK in python and it seems to be working but if someone can provide an answer I will happily take a REGEX answer over an NLP answer.